# SQL Server:- Importing Chinese Character Through Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am facing issue with importing chinese character into sql server.. It comes as weird ??? mark

I am using

```
DECLARE 
    @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Sproc NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Seperator NVARCHAR(10),
    @FullCommand NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Parameter_List NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @FullCommand = @Sproc + @Parameter_List

EXEC (@FullCommand) AT [POLODBC]
```

Please help how to get chinese character in correct form through this.

Below is the select statement I am trying to pool into Linked Server, Column PCN, Container_Status and Inventory Type is having chinese character.

```
    SELECT
  Plexus_Customer_Code = CAST(T.Plexus_Customer_Code as NVARCHAR(MAX)),
  T.Plexus_Customer_No,
  Container_Status = CAST(T.Container_Status AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
  T.Container_OK_Status,
  T.Container_Status_Key,
  PCN= CAST(T.PCN AS NVARCHAR(4000)),
  Report_Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR(100)) ,
  Building_Code = CAST(T.Building_Code AS NVARCHAR(100)),
  Part_No = CAST(T.Part_No AS NVARCHAR(50)),
  Revision = CAST(T.Revision AS NVARCHAR(50)),
  Part = CAST(T.Part_No + '-' + T.Revision AS NVARCHAR(100)),
  Planner = CAST(T.Planner AS NVARCHAR(100)),
  T.Part_Key,
  Name = CAST(T.[Name] AS NVARCHAR(100)),
  Inventory_Type = CAST(T.Inventory_Type AS NVARCHAR(100)),
  --Container_Status = CAST(T.Container_Status AS NVARCHAR(50)),
  SUM(T.Quantity) AS Quantity,
  COUNT(T.Serial_No) AS [Count],
  SUM(T.Quantity) * T.cost AS Inventory_Cost,
  T.Cost,
  Abbreviated_Inventory_Type = CAST(T.Abbreviated_Inventory_Type AS NVARCHAR(100)),
  Responsible_Plant = CAST(T.Responsible_Plant AS NVARCHAR(100)),
  Department_Code = CAST(T.Department_Code AS NVARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: You must provide the code within `@Sproc` to help you. There is - for sure - a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` (without the `N`) involved.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT '„普通話 / 普通话' AS SingleByteASCII ,N'„普通話 / 普通话' AS UnicodeUCS2;`